# how to send user to a specific page on clicking ngCordova local notification when app is in background

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Sending user to a specific view is working on clicking a local notification but only when app is in foreground, when i close app and get notification then it send on to the main page only which is defined in

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

for example, when we are not using WhatsApp and we get a new message notification and when we click it, it send us to that specific chat page not the main page of whatsapp, how can i achieve it?

## controller:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

    $scope.scheduleDelayedNotification = function () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var _5_SecondsFromNow = new Date(now + 5 * 1000);

        $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
            id: 1,
            title: 'New Notification',
            text: 'Notification Message',
            at: _5_SecondsFromNow
        }).then(function (result) {
            alert("Notification Set");
        });

        cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification, state) {
                $state.go('feedback');
        }, this)

        };
});
```

## app.js

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'localNotificationModule']);

ionicApp.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

ionicApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
  })
  .state('feedback', {
    url: '/feedback',
    templateUrl: 'views/feedback.html'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

});
```

## UPDATE:

## services.js

```
servicesModule.service('FirstRunScheduling', ['$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaLocalNotification', '$state', function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification, $state){

    var ref = new Firebase("https://feedback-system.firebaseio.com/TestTimeTable");

    ref.once("value", function(data) {
        var TestTimeTable = data.val().TestTimeTable;
        var notificationDate;
        var notificationID;
        if(data.val().first_run == false)
        {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                for(var i in TestTimeTable)
                {
                    notificationDate = new Date(TestTimeTable[i].year, TestTimeTable[i].month, TestTimeTable[i].day, TestTimeTable[i].hour, TestTimeTable[i].minute, 0, 0);
                    notificationID = i + ref.getAuth().uid.split(":")[1];
                    $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                        id: notificationID,
                        title: 'Feedback Reminder',
                        text: 'Please Provide Lecture Feedback',
                        at: notificationDate,
                        autoCancel: true
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        alert("Set");
                    });

                    cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification, state) {
                        $state.go('tabs.feedback');
                    }, this)
                }
            });
        }

        ref.update({
            first_run: true,
        });

    });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is being re-started when a user clicks on the notification then

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", ..)
```

will not have been called yet, as its only called when a new local notification is created.

Try registering the notification event handler within

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(...)
```

Comment: im new to angular and ionic, what i understood is i shud put it outside function "scheduleDelayedNotification", ill try it, thank

Comment: problem again, as u know it was working but when i do the same thing in a service, it doesnt send the user to that page, please check the updated code

Comment: its because cordove is not defined, eveything is injected but still.

Comment: My mistake, it is supposed to be so in browser :S
works now